# Increase amps with set voltage?

Tags: voltage, current, amperage

If I had a battery that is 50ah at 30V, what would I have to do to increase the current rating to 150ah, while maintaining the same voltage?

Comment: Your basic premise is wrong, therefore what you ask is unclear. 50Ah is not a current rating, but the battery’s capacity. It says nothing about the amount of current it can deliver. The current rating will be a different number (expressed in Ampere, not Ampere-hours). Look it up and change your question.

Comment: Get two more batteries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

150 Ah is a capacity rating, not a current rating. You may well find your existing battery can already deliver 150 amps.

If you want to increase the capacity from 50 Ah to 150 Ah, then you would need to put two more 50 Ah batteries in parallel with the first.

This would also increase by a factor of three whatever the current rating of your first battery was, assuming they were identical.

In order to find out what the current rating of your first battery is, you would need to look at the specifications. They normally give a C rating, which can be interpreted roughly as 'hours to fully discharge the battery'. Capacity falls as the output current increases, hence the qualifier 'roughly'.

A C rating of 1 means that the current rating is numerically equal to the capacity rating, which it looks like you are assuming. However, few batteries have a maximum C of 1.

There are different ratings for current. The two most frequently met are the maximum current that can be drawn safely, and the current for which the capacity rating is valid. With a car battery for instance, the maximum C is often around 10, for cranking the engine. However the maximum capacity C is often 0.1 or even 0.05, requiring a 10 or 20 hour discharge to obtain the stated Ah capacity.

Answer (score 1):

With "a" battery, you can't. Because, 50Ah is the maximum electrical charge (from Q = i × t) that the battery can contain and you can't increase it directly "in a single battery".

The only thing you can do is to connect 3 batteries in parallel. Since they are paralleled you'll get the same voltage (30V) with tripled capacity (3 × 50Ah).

Answer (score 0):

Putting it simply, three batteries in parallel. You are basically trying to draw more current (over time) than the battery can possibly handle.